# Fill in an image with text perfectly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to create an image with PILLOW which is complement filled with text.

I don't know how to set the perfect number of line and font size to do this.

Here is an example of the render I need :

[image]

Code I am working on :

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import textwrap


def draw_multiple_line_text(image, text, font, text_color, text_start_height):
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    image_width, image_height = image.size
    y_text = text_start_height
    lines = textwrap.wrap(text, width=60)
    for line in lines:
        line_width, line_height = font.getsize(line)
        print(line_width, line_height)
        draw.text(((image_width - line_width) / 2, y_text), line, font=font, fill=text_color)
        y_text += line_height


def main():
    image = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), color=(0, 0, 0))
    fontsize = 20  # starting font size
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", fontsize)
    text = "No, woman, no cry No, woman, no cry No, woman, no cry No, woman, no cry 'Cause, 'cause, 'cause I remember when we used to sit In the government yard in Trenchtown Oba observing the 'ypocrites Mingle with the good people we meet Good friends we have, oh, good friends we've lost Along the way In this great future, you can't forget your past So dry your tears, I seh No, woman, no cry No, woman, no cry 'Ere, little darlin', don't shed no tears No, woman, no cry Said, said, said, I remember when-a we used to sit In the government yard in Trenchtown And then Georgie would make the fire lights, I seh A log wood burnin' through the night Then we would cook cornmeal porridge, I seh Of which I'll share with you My feet is my only carriage And so I've got to push on through… "

    text_color = (200, 200, 200)
    text_start_height = 0
    draw_multiple_line_text(image, text, font, text_color, text_start_height)
    image.save('pil_text.png')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Current render :

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a problem of font and size; in fact, for most text, those choices are insufficient to give a perfect fill.

Look carefully at the target text: the perfection comes from inserting appropriate spaces between the words of each line.  You have to go through the text, filling each line as far as you can.  Once you determine where the line breaks belong, then you make a second pass, distributing spaces as needed to extend the right-most character to the right margin.

To do this, you compute the shortfall, divide that by the width of your unit space (this differs with font), and then evenly distribute those spaces to the existing spaces in teh text.  "Evenly" is a process of your choice.

Comment: I'm a little bit stuck. How can I change the spaces between characters ?
I can't make calculations with the current data.

Comment: What do you mean, "I can't make calculations"?  What stops you?  You have the text in a string, you have a choice of font and with all available attributes.